# transpose project with PreferenceActivity/appcompat-v7:28.0.0 to PreferenceFragmentCompat/androidx

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I want to transpose the project below api level 22 to api level 28

I stay taking PreferenceActivity of project links below and I put PreferenceFragmentCompat: [1]:http://ryanfx.blogspot.com/2013/06/raspberry-pi-powered-android-controlled.html

This is my current code:[2]:https://github.com/ryanfx/GarageAndroid/blob/master/src/com/blogspot/ryanfx/activity/ConfigurationActivity.java

I have issue of the picture below and this is my project (with issue):[3]:https://github.com/neuberfran/AlarmController/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/neuberfran/activity/ConfigurationActivity.java

[image: issue][4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sVg-wBMvwPFZwY3VehVuGrUMZHcP6ETc/view?usp=sharing)

**What is the best way to transpose project with PreferenceActivity/appcompat-v7:28.0.0 to androidx/PreferenceFragmentCompat** ?

Comment: What do you mean "transpose"? Have you tried the tool of the IDE to convert to Android-x ?

Comment: @android developer Hi, I put api 28 in build.gradle and clicked on menu -> refactor -> migrate to AndroidX, and in file ConfigurationActivity.kt
there was no automatic exchange of PreferenceActivity to PreferenceFragmentCompat.

the two screens below, show my issue. In the second, I do not have the AccountManager correctly, because of the first.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDzAW-1TbDJ924VS97YGuSd8nBOe3GgT/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18tMJruFJMWGFEPeodbkiwr9uA7p8cHq6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have `setPreferencesFromResource` commented out in your project? You need to call that method before you try and call `findPreference`, or else it will just return null

You should do this inside onCreatePreferences, not onCreate - see the sample project [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-preferences/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidx/preference/sample/MainActivity.kt) for an example

Comment: @Louis I have new issues now: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1muTuwozTJ7bSA5bVX-y8RKmlWdWIneMV?usp=sharing   https://drive.google.com/file/d/19azy3sJa5WJHISaPSY3v9t7_PxWIHusZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For the first issue, your 'ConfigurationActivity' is not an activity, it is now a Fragment, so you need to pass `getContext()` instead of `this`.

For the second issue, remove all `android.preference` imports, and make sure you are only importing the `androidx.preference` classes - you cannot mix both together

Comment: @Louis new Issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHUwyf7pJ-P0rSZiEBW_ECYAECJGMcYc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, this is now a Fragment, not an activity. So you need to use the `supportFragmentManager` to show the fragment inside an activity, you can't launch this fragment directly.

Comment: @Louis work (more or less) only with getSupportFragmentManager but not with supportFragmentManager AND accountmanager issue remains.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BUepzWxB1FDWpgMD2CquP0XAqZ6UgmZ8?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, `getSupportFragmentManager` is correct - I don't understand what is happening in the account screenshot. Can you update the github repo with the new code?

Comment: @Louis https://github.com/neuberfran/GarageAndroid-master/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/ryanfx/activity/MainActivity.java

Comment: @Louis I think supportFragmentManager only works with kotlin and androidx/ktx or in Java with appcompat-v7/v8. I'm checking cases on the internet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS9jhuHECEQ  https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-android-jetpack-preferences   https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-how-to-implement-listpreference/

Comment: Ok, so the issue is you are setting the activity's view, and also adding a fragment to  your activity:


   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, new ConfigurationActivity () );
    .commit();

It looks like you actually want a separate activity, that displays the settings. So just rename ConfigurationActivity to ConfigurationFragment, create a new ConfigurationActivity that extends AppCompatActivity, and make it show the fragment. And then in  MainActivity, you just link to configuration activity like before

Comment: supportFragmentManager and getSupportFragmentManager() are the same thing, the first one is just the Kotlin syntax to access it.

Comment: @Louis First, we have to undo a mess. The code:
supportFragmentManager
 .beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.xml.server_config, new ConfigurationActivity () );
        .commit()

is not working. I changed the code there and got a new error.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hAl7TSgY4nvTQ9zjo-o7T2qr8cidUUNn/view?usp=sharing  I think I need put <androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen in my  server_config.xml. I don't put it yet.

Comment: @Louis, Ok now I'm back to this issue:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GqOaVjDmmtUOlmjtuVZ1XxOfgFVqEndz/view?usp=sharing

and I will try the changes proposed by you. with getSupportFragmentManager and not with supportFragmentManager. This is new issue with changes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11s2Dn61kADP9lJNeIwjs5N5LetEU4aRr/view?usp=sharing after I clicked in Settings menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195985/discussion-between-louis-and-neuber).